# How is IdP-initiated working with MVC in the ITFoxtec.Identity examples?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I feel like I'm missing something, either in my understanding of SSO, or in how IdP-initiated in the example projects (MVC and Core) at [ITFoxtec.Identity.Saml2](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) are working.

It seems like the only project set up to be the IdP is TestIdPCore, yet the only projects that have IdPInitiatedController seem to be set up to only be an Service Provider (relying party?).

I dropped IdPInitiatedController into TestIdPCore and was able to get Initiate() to work.

I guess I am confused on how to get IdP-initiated working with the examples as they are.

Thank you for your time, both in the work done and in your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you understand IdP-initiated correct. In the old days the solution did not contain the TestIdPCore IdP sample. Therefore, the IdP-initiated sample is placed in a SP (Service Provider).
But you are right, I should move it to the IdP sample.

If you like, you are welcome to do a pull request to move the IdP-initiated sample to the TestIdPCore IdP sample.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
I will submit a pull request as soon as I'm able.